# In Kabbadi how much time does a raider have after being captured by a defender to escape?

Tags: rules, kabaddi

If a raider is caught by defenders, but crosses the line after 10 seconds, does he earn a point?

Answer (score 2):

The raider is out when they lose their chant:

> A raider shall continue to chant “KABADDI” as the approved cant. If he is not keeping the proper approved cant in the opponent’s court, he shall be declared out and the opponent will be awarded one point and the chance to raid.

(Source: [Pro Kabaddi Rules](https://www.prokabaddi.com/prokabaddi-rules))

so as long as they maintain their chant (and manage to return to their court within the 30s raid limit if that applies in the match), then they get the point.